# >= issue when pulling dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having trouble with the following query: Cannot seem to get my `WHERE` statement to work properly with respect to the order date. Looking to pull all dates after a specific date. or all dates before that specific date.

```
SELECT TOP (10000) [Order_Product_ID]
      ,[Order_ID]
      ,[Order_Date_Key]
      ,[Activation_Date_Key]
      ,[Order_Type_Key]
      ,[Product_Key]
      ,[Shipment_Type_Key]
      ,format([Order_Date],'yyyy-MM-dd') as date
      ,[Activation_Date]
      ,[Order_Cancel_Date]
      ,[Order_Planned_Shipment_Date]
      ,[Order_Actual_Shipment_Date]
      ,[Order_Product_Cost_Amount]
      ,[Order_Product_Revenue_Amount]
      ,[Order_Product_Marketing_Discount_Amount]
      ,[Order_Product_Sales_Discount_Amount]
      ,[Order_Product_Special_Offer_Discount_Amount]
      ,[Order_Product_Support_Discount_Amount]
      ,[Order_Product_Return_Item_Discount_Amount]
      ,[Order_Product_Shipment_Amount]
      ,[Order_Days_To_Ship]
      ,[Offer_Key]
      ,[Order_Is_Return]
      ,[Order_Return_Is_Valid]
      ,[Product_Replacement_Reason_Key]
      ,[Product_Retail_cost]
      ,[Product_Company_cost]
      ,[Insert_Audit_Key]
      ,[Update_Audit_Key]
  FROM [BIS].[dbo].[Fact_Order_Product]
  WHERE  order_type_key = '1' or order_type_key = '2'and  Order_Date >= '2017-02-22';
```

Comment: Use parentheses when combining `AND` and `OR` in the `WHERE`. (Or, in fact, use `IN` instead of the `OR`)

Comment: I removed the database tag, because this no question on how to design a database. I've added a tag for SQL Server, because this is the DBMS I guess you are using. SQL questions should always be tagged with the DBMS in question.

Answer (score 3):

You need parentheses for the way that you have phrased the logic.

But I would recommend `in`:

```
WHERE order_type_key IN (1, 2) AND
      order_Date >= '2017-02-22';
```

Note that I removed the single quotes from `1` and `2`, because they look like numbers.  If they are really strings, keep the single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to achieve it.

```
(order_type_key = '1' or order_type_key = '2') and  Order_Date >= '2017-02-22';
```

OR

```
order_type_key in ('1', '2') and  Order_Date >= '2017-02-22';
```